# Python : How to transform a base class exception into RuntimeError?

Tags: python, class, exception, runtimeexception

When I build a class, let's say `Myclass`, I usuallly write a class exception using :

```
class MyclassError(Exception):
    pass
```

What if I want to raise `RuntimeError` in this class ? (to transform all `MyclassExceptions` into `RuntimeErrors` ?), something like :

```
class MyclassError(Exception):
    raise RuntimeError(self)
```

Comment: class MyclassError(RuntimeError, Exception):

Comment: Not sure what you're intending there.  You can make `MyclassError` inherit from `RuntimeError`, which would enable it to be caught with `except RuntimeError`.  The class doesn't raise the exception, it *is* the exception.

Comment: what are you actually wanting to  do?

Comment: @xfx: Since `RuntimeError` is a subclass of `Exception`, it's better to just write `class MyclassError(RuntimeError)`. But otherwise… I thin that may be what he actually wants, but it's so hard to tell…

Comment: Why don't you just use `RuntimeError` instead of defining your own?

Comment: By the way, the code you wrote _is_ actually valid… it's just not particularly useful. You can execute any code you want in the middle of a class definition; executing a `raise` just aborts the class definition and either gets caught somewhere above or percolates to the top to print out a traceback and exit.

Comment: Another way: class MyclassError(Exception):
 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
  raise RuntimeError(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: I could raise RuntimeError in Myclass, but it is neatter to raise MyclassError, and define MyclassError. The purpose is to catch all errors using RuntimeError. Thanks for your answers. Personnally, I will use BrenBarn's solution.